# Receiving the error: “Cannot subscript a value of type ‘[Double]’ with an index of type ‘(Any) -> Int’”

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I’m receiving the error:

> “Cannot subscript a value of type ‘[Double]’ with an index of type ‘(Any) -> Int’” on the following line of code:

```
tipPer = tipPercentages[index]
```

Here is the rest of my code (including the erroneous line): ((sorry for the terrible formatting/syntax, I’m new to Swift!))

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var tipPer: Int = 0

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    @IBOutlet weak var tipLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var perPersonLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var billField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var peopleField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tipControl: UISegmentedControl!


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // This is a good place to retrieve the default tip percentage from UserDefaults
        // and use it to update the tip amount
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func onTap(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        view.endEditing(true)
    }


    @IBAction func calculateTip(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let tipPercentages = [0.10, 0.15, 0.20]

        defaults.synchronize()



        if (tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
            let index = tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        }

        if (tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
            let index = tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        }

        if (tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
            let index = tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        }

        if (tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 3) {

            let index = defaults.integer(forKey: "defaultTipControlKey")
        }


        let tipPer = tipPercentages[index]
        let bill = Double(billField.text!) ?? 0
        let people = Double(peopleField.text!) ?? 1

        let tip = bill * tipPer
        let total = bill + tip
        let perPerson = total / people

        tipLabel.text = String(format: "$%.2f", tip)
        totalLabel.text = String(format: "$%.2f", total)
        perPersonLabel.text = String(format: "$%.2f Each", perPerson)

    }
}
```

I know that it has to do something with setting the index variable to an integer, which I attempted to do, but I’m missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how are you using `index`? Since all `index` are defined inside `if {` statements? `index` is something else in `tipPercentages[index]`.

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `index` constant that you have declared inside of all the `if block` so its scope is corresponding to that `if block` so it is not available after `if block` for you. To solve the problem declare index variable before your for if block and instead of creating multiple if block you only need single `if condition` like this.

```
var index = defaults.integer(forKey: "defaultTipControlKey") //Default value
if (tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex != 3) {
    index = tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex
}
let tipPer = tipPercentages[index]
```

**Note:** Your `if condition` doesn't make any sense you simply want above one single `if block` to get the index.